# Approximate the Riemann sum with comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, sicp

I am following the sicp to compute the integral with Riemann sum:

```
#+begin_src ipython :session sicp :results output
def integral(f, a, b, dx):
    add_dx = lambda x: x + dx
    return sum_recur(f, a+(dx/2), add_dx, b) * dx

from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def sum_recur(term, a, next, b):
    if a > b: return 0
    return term(a) + sum_recur(term, next(a), next, b)

def cube(x): return x ** 3

print(integral(cube, 0, 1, 0.01))

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 0.24998750000000042
```

It works properly, but when implement it with list comprehension

```
#+begin_src ipython :session sicp :results output
def integral(f, a, b, dx):
    return sum(a+dx/2+n*dx for n in range(b-1)) * dx
print(integral(cube, 0, 1, 0.001))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 5e-07
```

It does not work as expected, what's the problem?

Comment: It seems strange to me that you never call your `f` function in the second example. Also `range(a-b)` equals `range(-1)` with your `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the `range(a-b)` part is evaluating `range(-1)`. Also, you aren't calling your `cube` function anywhere.

Try this:

```
def cube(x): return x ** 3

def integral(f, a, b, dx):
    return sum(f(a+dx/2+n*dx) for n in range(int((b-a)/dx)) ) * dx

print(integral(cube, 0, 1, 0.01))
```

Prints:

```
0.24998750000000006
```

Comment: so, the well-recommended list comprehension fight about the principle of independent to particular computations with abstraction.